# Error in the function reshape() in matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I have this following code to read the Y component in the CIF sequence , which is throwing this error.

Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in foremanOne (line 12)
    img_y = reshape(img_y, nColumn, nRow);

the code is

```
            clc;
            file = 'foreman.cif';
            nFrame = 10;
            [fid,message]= fopen(file,'rb');
            nRow = 288;
            nColumn = 352;

            for i = 1: nFrame
                %reading Y component 
                img_y = fread(fid, nRow * nColumn, 'uchar');
                img_y = reshape(img_y, nColumn, nRow);
                img_y = img_y';
                imshow(uint8(img_y));
            end

            fclose(fid);
            disp('OK');
```

What might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you don't use `i` so it looks like the array `img_y` you  open with `fread` is of dimensions `[288, 352, 10]` whereas when you reshape you only provide the height and width of the image.
Therefore I think you simply need to index `img_y` with the loop index (I changed from i to k... i is not a so good idea as its the imaginary unit) like so:

```
           clc;
            file = 'foreman.cif';
            nFrame = 10;
            [fid,message]= fopen(file,'rb');
            nRow = 288;
            nColumn = 352;

         %// Use fread once outside the loop and convert right away everything to uint8.
          img_y = uint8(fread(fid, nRow * nColumn, 'uchar'));

            for k = 1:nFrame
                %// reading Y component. I changed the name to avoid confusion
                ImY = reshape(img_y(:,:,k), nColumn, nRow); %// Use index here
                ImY = ImY';
                imshow(ImY);

            pause(0.5) %// You might want to pause to see each image individually
            end

            fclose(fid);
            disp('OK');
```

I made some other changes as well to make the code a bit more efficient.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for accepting! I just noticed that `ImY` is reshaped to have dimensions `[nColumn,nRow]`. Since in MATLAB rows come first during indexing you might want to swap them.

Comment: I tried to execute the code but the error is still the same!!

Comment: Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in foremanOne (line 31)
                ImY = reshape(img_y(:,:,k), nColumn, nRow);

Comment: well provide more information because it's hard to guess here. What's the size of "file"? Please show the output of a call to `whos` after the call to `fopen`. Thanks

Comment: Name         Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  fid          1x1                 8  double              
  file         1x11               22  char                
  message      0x0                 0  char                
  nFrame       1x1                 8  double              

Error using  ' 
Transpose on ND array is not defined.

Error in foremanOne (line 14)
                ImY = ImY';